# Connecting switch in parallel to ESP32 output GPIO

Tags: diodes, esp32, uln2003

I want to make a circuit where an ESP32 or a button should controll a relay. The button receives power from a different PS ([LD1117AV33](https://www.mouser.ch/datasheet/2/389/cd00002116-1795864.pdf))

This is a potential diagram:
[image]

1. What would happen if the button sends 3.3v to an output pin of the ESP32?
2. What happens if both the ESP and the button send 3.3v at the same time?
3. Do I need to protect the ESP32 GPIO from the power sent by the button? If yes, can I do that with a LED? (D1) Would I still have enough V to turn on the [ULN2003A](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/uln2001.pdf)?

Datasheets:

- ULN2003A: https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/uln2001.pdf
- LD1117AV33: https://www.mouser.ch/datasheet/2/389/cd00002116-1795864.pdf

Comment: You should describe what you want to achieve. The circuit as shown won't do much: the LED is either reverse biased, connected to a high impedance node or doesn't see any voltage. There is no path for current to flow in any of those states.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't recognize the ULN2003 was bipolar, so it might be fine if the LED can handle the reverse voltage. What load does the ULN2003 have to drive? Its base current will be ~100uA, giving a max load current of 100mA.

Comment: Thanks @SimSon. ULN2003A will drive 4 relays (80mA each my raugh calculation)... I thought it did not matter what is behind the IC.

Comment: Bipolar transistors are "current amplifiers", so yes, the load does matter. When used as a switch, there should be some margin. 80mA would be a bit too much here for my taste. The circuit might behave slightly different when the button is pressed and when IO23 is high.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ULN200x is based on bipolar transistors which are "current amplifiers". That means the required base current depends on the load to drive. To drive an 80mA relay, the base current must be *at least* 80µA (the darlinghton pair in the ULN200x has a current gain of 1000), but there should be some margin to be save.

Assuming the LED drops 3V only 0.3V remain for the ULN2003, which results in ~100µA of base current (2.7kOhm base resistance) and a maximum load current of ~100mA.

The circuit will behave differently depending on whether it is activated with the switch or IO23. In the first case, the ULN will see full 3.3V - allowing >1A load current -  while there's almost no margin in the latter.

This is how I would do it:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5p8Jv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You can choose to place the LED branch directly at IO23 if you want it to light up when the relay is activated by the ESP32 or you can leave it out completely.

Note 1: this circuit should behave like *I belive* you want your circuit to behave like, but you didn't explain the desired behavior. The relay will be enabled if either the switch is pressed *or* IO23 is high. It will only be disabled if the switch is not pressed *and* IO23 is low.

Note 2: if you want to stick with your circuit, you have to choose an LED that is unidirectional but can handle reverse voltage!

Comment: Thanks a lot @SimSon. I added a Led because I thought it was the exact same thing as a diode. If it is not, then I don't need the extra led. But you opened a new door in here. If the 3.3v are comming from an external power supply. Do I need a resistor after the switch?

Comment: @CarlosGarcia you theoretically do not need an extra resistor after the switch if the IO is protected by a diode. But I'd recommend you add one: due t the recovery time of the diode, it might conduct in reverse direction for a short time. 100 Ohm or so is sufficient.

Comment: but what about the ULN2003? Don;t i need a resistor to protect that part of the circuit?

Comment: @CarlosGarcia the ULN200**3** has an internal 2.7 kOhm base resistor, so you don't need an extra resistor. But the other variants of the ULN200X are different (datasheet, page 3).

Comment: one last question. Wouldn't I need a pull down resistor in I1? When the button is open and IO23 LOW, it gives me the feeling that I1 is floating since the diode will not allow the ESP to bring it to LOW

Comment: @CarlosGarcia the ULN2003 has a 10k pulldown already, so I don't think an extra one is neccessary.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your answers!

Answer (score 2):

1. If the ESP32 output pin is set low and it is connected to 3.3V via button, it will exceed absolute maximum current rating which can lead to permanent degradation or damage to the ESP32. Don't short circuit outputs to VCC or GND.
2. Nothing will happen if ESP32 output pin is high and it is also externally connected to VCC.
3. Yes you need to protect from short circuiting ESP32 output externally. If you can use a LED or not depends which kind of LED and how much current the ULN must sink. Most likely even a red LED will drop too much voltage to reliably drive ULN input.